# Access NSDocument from NSViewController and vice versa

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, nsdocument, nsviewcontroller

What is the correct way to access the NSDocument subclass from its associated NSViewController subclass and vice versa?

I have the following code that does the former, but it doesn't work when the view has loaded or when it moved to a window:

```
var document: Document {
    return NSDocumentController.sharedDocumentController().documentForWindow(view.window!) as! Document
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Accessing NSDocument from NSViewController

The document can be accessed from the view controller via this property (**Document** is a subclass of **NSDocument**):

```
var document: Document? {
    return view.window?.windowController?.document as? Document
}
```

This property will return **nil** in the **viewDidLoad** method, but will return the document in the **viewDidAppear** method.

### Accessing NSViewController from NSDocument

The view controller can be accessed from the document via this property (**ViewController** is a subclass of **NSViewController**):

```
var viewControllers: [ViewController] {
    var result: [ViewController] = []
    for windowController in windowControllers {
        if let viewController = windowController.contentViewController as? ViewController {
            result.append(viewController)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

In case you only create one window controller in your **makeWindowControllers** method:

```
var viewController: ViewController? {
    return windowControllers[0].contentViewController as? ViewController
}
```

Comment: In my case, I need the array of data in the `Document` for the `outlineView`. `NSOutlineView` automatically calls the `numberOfChildrenOfItem` during the `viewDidLoad` process and to determine the number of children for the `outlineView` I need the data in the `Document`. That makes the app crashes.